# How to change particular database columns value in in django framework

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hi i am try to solve reset password through dynamically .. what i doing some one register my form it will store in my database all fields value storing, But i have give one more connection just like reset password through by mail if some one submit email it will go to email id and he will link their for reset password in that page i am password and conform password, this form it should go to the same register database in that particular field is that password, conform password only change not other value .. but in my code what happening updating password but remains column values showing null

#### View.py

def reset_password(request,id):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and Register.objects.all():
        if Register.objects.get(id=id):
            print('re')
            password = request.POST['password']
            password1 = request.POST['password1']
            # Validation
            #reg = Register.objects.filter(password='65789')
            #for obj in reg:
             #   obj.password1 = '65789'
              #  obj.save()

            arr = Register(id=id,password=password,password1=password1)
            #user = Register(id=id,arr)
            arr.save()
            return HttpResponse('New password succesfully stored ')

return render(request,'reset_password.html')
```

##Mysql Database ..in that 24 id please check it you will get idea, i dnot want reset django frame work that why i am trying this way please any one help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicsu.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question you want to send a Password reset link to the user.
Django already has a simple way to do this. You need to use the following views:-

- **PasswordResetView**
- **PasswordResetDoneView**
- **PasswordResetConfirmView**
- **PasswordResetCompleteView**

here is a [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html#password-reset) you might find helpful.
To answer your actual question though something like this should work:-

```
register_obj = Register.objects.get(id=id)
register_obj.password = new_password
register_obj.password1 = new_password
register_obj.save()
```